# Security concerns when uploading data to Azure Blob Storage directly from frontend

Tags: azure

I am working on a project where we have to store some audio/video files on Azure Blob Storage and after the file is uploaded we need to calculate some price on the basis of the length of the file in minutes. We have an Angular frontend and the idea was to upload the file directly from the frontend, get the response from Azure with the file stats , then call a backend API to put that data in the database.

What I am wondering is what are the chances of manipulation of data in between getting the file data back from Azure and calling our backend API. Is there any chance the length could be modified before sending it to our API?

Comment: How are you planning on getting the callback from Azure when the file is uploads? Also, I am assuming the blobs will be uploaded as block blobs. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes block blobs. Well to be fair I have limited experience with Azure and I am assuming it will be something similar to how S3 handles uploads. By callback I do mean a JavaScript callback or promise so basically the asynchronous response after the upload finishes.

Comment: What we were thinking is using a webhook to pass the data directly to our backend API from Azure first and then maybe firing a socket to get the data back to the frontend or just have the webhook happen along with the normal HTTP response from Azure. But it seems an overengineered solution for something that might not even be a problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to make use of [`Azure Event Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema) with Blob integration. Whenever a blob is uploaded, an event will be raised automatically that you can consume in an Azure Function and save the data in your database.

There's a possibility that a user might re-upload same file with different size. If that happens, you will get another event (apart from the original event when the blob was first created). How you handle with updates would be entirely up to you.

Comment: Events in Azure Event Grid are similar to webhooks am I correct?  Reuploading is not a problem we have considered actually. The concern is more about uploading a 10 minute file but sending that its only 5 minutes long. I think this solution could work.

Comment: `Events in Azure Event Grid are similar to webhooks am I correct?` - Kind of, yes. `The concern is more about uploading a 10 minute file but sending that its only 5 minutes long.` - This is more like an application concern as to how you do the validation of the files being uploaded by the users.